# Is use="optional" in xsd redundant?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Does it matter for any purpose (validation, binding ...) if I define the `use` of an `xs:attribute` as `optional` or do not define it at all?
If it is redundant, why is it provided at all?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it's redundant.

This [section of the XSD Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints) explains the gory details of occurrence constraints, but here's the relevant part:

> (the default value of `use` is `optional`)

As with all explicitly specified values that match their defaults: It's just a way to distinguish "don't care" from "i actually want that value".

Answer (score 7):

Many language designers try to follow a principle that if there are several options, and one is the default, then you should be able to request the default explicitly rather than merely relying on saying nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It is the default value, so yes it is redundant. It may be provided for markup creators who wish to indicate that they had indeed given thought to the usage, or possibly to allow easier dynamic switching of the value when creating a schema programmatically.